# Bandwidth throttling with onboard tools in Yosemite?

Tags: network, safari, quicktime, firewall

Is there any way with Mac OS Yosemite's built-in firewall to throttle or queue connections from a single application, on a single port or to a certain hostname?

The App in question would be the Quicktime plugin in Safari - ever since the HTML5 beta I've been using that on Youtube instead of flash, for obvious reasons. But while the videos are loading, my internet connection is so saturated, that everything else comes to a halt, sometimes other applications even time out.

Since all questions answered here and tutorials floating around are hopelessly outdated I hope someone can help me with this annoyance without relying on third party tools, since I can't seem to find anything that works with my intended case.

Comment: there's a method to add specifically throttled pipes here - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44130/how-can-i-limit-my-download-bandwidth though you might find that your ISP or home router are already prioritising your data steam the other way round, actively favouring video connections over non-time-sensitive data. Check if your router has a download QoS & see if it's better on or off. If it's your ISP, then it's back to manually piping it, as in the link

Comment: This looks good, I'll look into that.

Comment: Wish you luck, Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Oh. Right. Except for the fact, that ipfw is gone for good. Is there a guide like this for Yosemites pf?

Comment: ach, sorry, wasn't aware - not gone to Yosemite yet. Did you check your router for QoS? I'm afraid fiddling with pf is waay above my skillset, sorry. I do all my gateway/router etc in a nice web interface, on Sophos UTM so I don't have to brave raw nix.

Comment: Yes, the router has no QoS built in.