# Bandwidth limiting in Yosemite

Tags: mac, network, macos, internet

I get disconnected from the internet whenever the speed reaches 2.5 Mbps

Is there any app to limit the internet speed below that. I am not talking per application based.

Using MacBook Pro (mid 2013) Yosemite

Comment: Is there an administrative reason for the disconnect or is it due technical problems with your network (especially with your modem)?

Comment: The isp does not allow speed more than 2.5 Mbps. I m using a 21 Mbps modem. Recently the tower got upgraded and whenever the speed crosses the limit, the internet gets disconnected. The ISP are yet to fix this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use Network Link Conditioner.

[image: Network Link Conditioner Preference Pane]

You will want to ignore the testing settings. Make a **Custom Profile** and set to have no packets dropped and no delay. Start with uplink and downlink at 2.45 Mbps each and see if you need lower limits to prevent disconnects.

[image: Network Link Conditioner Custom Profiles]

It is a free download in Xcode (go to Xcode → Open Developer Tool → More Developer Tools… and download the **Hardware IO Tools for Xcode**).

Comment: It works perfect. For future reference there is no need to download Xcode, for the hardware IO Tools. It can be downloaded directly from apple developer website

Comment: You can download it here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/
(sign in with your apple ID)

Comment: This is no longer working for me on macOS Sierra

Comment: @Tariq You need to use the latest version of Network Link Conditioner, update yours

Comment: I have downloaded latest version today for developer.apple.com which is fairly old. Apple have not released a new version compatible to Sierra

Comment: @Tariq https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ Additional Tools for Xcode 8.1, it really does work if you have the latest version

Comment: It looks as if I have to run my app (a Chrome browser in my case) in "the simulator" before the conditioning takes place. I'm using macOS Sierra and XCode 8.3.3 after downloading the Hardware IO Tools for Xcode 7.3 dated Mar 20, 2016. There is no download newer than that one. All I'm trying to do is simulate a slow network for my entire MBP while running my test.

Comment: I tried this with MacOs Mojave. `iperf` always shows the same results: 1000Mbps. Seems this does not work anymore.